# Criteria API. Predicate with OrderBy expression

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have a repo with own `Specification` implementation with `toPredicate` method as main query construction  and I try to add `order by` expression:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(@NotNull Root<Strategy> root,
                             @NotNull CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                             @NotNull CriteriaBuilder builder) {
     Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
     List<Expression<Boolean>> exps = predicate.getExpressions();

     ... adding different expressions to exps.add(...)

     // I get an id for descending sort due to Postgres just increment it.
     Order orderBy = builder.desc(root.get("id"));
     Expression<?> expression = orderBy.getExpression();

     // Problem here.
     exps.add(expression);
     return predicate;
}
```

Expression from `orderBy.getExpression()` is `<?>` generic but original expressions list expect `<Boolean>` type. How to connect them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Specification` is only intended for encoding where-clauses. If you want to order your result use a [`Sort` instance as an additional parameter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort-).

Comment: Then do the sorting via the `Pageable` and not in the `Specification`

Answer (score 0):

Sorting with pagination means sorting should be field of `Pageable` like this:

```
Pageable pagination = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by("id").descending());
```